# Update the iTH element of a list - 'Nonetype Object is not subscribable' error

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an AI for TicTacToe. I declare the board with this method:

```
def initial_state():
    """
    Returns new board.
    """
    return [[None, None, None],
            [None, None, None],
            [None, None, None]]
```

I also created a function to detect which moves are possible, given a certain board. It returns a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the coordinates of an empty case.

```
def actions(board): 
        L=set()
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if board[i][j]=='EMPTY':
                L.update([(i,j)])
    return L
```

And here is the function causing the error. This function takes 2 parameters:

board: The current board

a: a tuple containing the (x,y) coordinates of the move to make (AKA The case where we will put an X or an O depending on which player's turn it is.)

```
def result(board, a):
    """
    Returns the board that results from making move (i, j) on the board.
    """
    new_board=copy.deepcopy(board)
    if new_board[a[0]][a[1]] is not None:  ***#(this is line 57, the line causing the error)***
        raise NameError('Case already full')
    if player(new_board)=='X':   #function player will return the player whose turn it is.
        new_board[a[0]][a[1]]='X'
    else:
        new_board[a[0]][a[1]]='O'

    return new_board
```

The error I get: Python error: 'NoneType' object is not subscribable (line 57).

Comment: When you are calling the result function, is the a parameter set to something? The thing is on that line the issue can be on both of the variables, both the new_board and a.

Comment: yes a is set to a pair of coordinates (x,y). More precisely, a will be assigned a value in this loop : for a in actions(board). And here is the function actions:               
   `L=set()
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if board[i][j]=='EMPTY':
                L.update([(i,j)])
    return L `(I couldn't write the code correctly in the comment, so I'll write it down below, as an answer to my question)

Comment: Instead of adding code to the comments, or as an answer, in order to clarify the question, [edit] the question instead.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: error should show you in which line is problem - so use `print()` to see values in variables in this line. it is called "print debuging".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! a was returning None. I had to change the boolean expression in the actions() function:
if board[i][j]=='EMPTY' TO ***if board[i][j]==None***

That none notation got me lost a bit as it was my first time using it, thank you for your help!